# Properties of operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, terminology

I am having trouble understanding properties of operators

For an operator $\hat{A}$ which of the following would be correct:

1. $\int{(\hat{A}\phi)^*\psi}=\int{\hat{A}^*\phi^*\psi}$
2. $\int{(\hat{A}\phi)^*\psi}=\int{\phi^*\hat{A}^*\psi}$

---

Is the following allowed in any case?

$\int{\phi\hat{A}\psi}=\int{\hat{A}\phi\psi}$

$\int{\psi^*(\hat{A}\hat{B})^\dagger\psi}=\int{(\hat{A}\hat{B})^\dagger}\psi^*\psi$

- for example when the operator is Hermitian

edit:

- $\dagger$ here is the Hermitian conjugate
- $*$ is the complex conjugate
- $A^\dagger \ne A^*$

Comment: "in any case" - that's ambiguous. Do you mean "in every case" or "ever"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's worth knowing that in a vector space over the complex numbers the notion of complex conjugtion is basis dependent.  In the diagonal-$\hat x$ basis $|x\rangle$  the momentum operator $\hat p \to -i\partial_x$  would change sign when conjugated, but in the diagonal $\hat p$ basis $| p\rangle$ the momentum operator  $\hat p$ is just multiplication by the real number $p$. As a consequence  the "complex conjugate" of an operator is not really a definable concept.